# To write a function, to get the next folder level in the file path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql server, I need to do a task where a function should be created, and in that, a string of a file path will be given as an input parameter and it should give the rest of the file path as output.

For example, "Users\appu\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects" is the file path, here if I give Users as input parameter it should give the next folder level, or if I give Documents as input parameter, it should give next folder level after that which is '\Visual Studio 2008'.
In this way I need to write a function, can you guys help me in this please.

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
declare @Str nvarchar(max), @SearchStr nvarchar(max)
set @Str='Users\appu\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects'
set @SearchStr='appu'

SELECT STUFF(@Str, 1, CHARINDEX(@SearchStr+'\', @Str)+LEN(@SearchStr), '')
```

Comment: Hi, when I created a function for the above code, its giving different result.. This is my function:

Comment: Hi, when I created a function for the above code, its giving different result.. This is my function:                                      create function fn_tofindnextfolderlevel(@str nvarchar(max),@SearchStr nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar
as
Begin
      return (SELECT STUFF(@Str, 1, CHARINDEX(@SearchStr+'\',              @Str)+LEN(@SearchStr), ''))
End                                                                 And when I call the function with parameters say select dbo.fn_tofindnextfolderlevel
('Users\appu\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects','Documents')      now its giving only 'V'